# Silverlight Unit Testing, Dealing with Async calls in nested methods

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, specflow

When creating Unit Tests for silverlight the test framework seems to have features build in to help with Async calls but only within the test method. What if in a child method of the one you are calling there is an Async call.

As an example we use Specflow to test our ViewModels, We want to call the Execute method of a command and that command then asynchronously calls a web service. How can i ensure the while command is completed before asserting the results?

as an example this is the command

```
    [Asynchronous]
    [When(@"I press calculate")]
    public void WhenIPressCalculate()
    {
        _helloWorldViewModel.CalculateCommand.Execute(null);
    }
```

I need to wait for the entire command to complete before continuing.

Comment: If the async call is related with WCF service, you can create a mock service which doesn't have delays in method calls. And it is better approach because unit tests must not take much time to complete.

Comment: We are actually testing Blocks of functionality (Behaviour Driven Development) so it is good that we are calling a real service. That way we can ensure the feature is working in its entirety.

Answer (score 0):

make a loop in the same method with an exit condition that execution has finished.

Answer (score 0):

A loop does not work when making a call to a network service because the callback is marshalled to the UI Thread, if it is looping for a condition it creates a deadlock as the call back is waiting for the thread to finish.

Anyway we soted this problem out. turns out the specflow guys were working on this at the same time and have a solution in progress. We got it working with a pre release build.

I wrote a blog entry about it here http://rburnham.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/testing-silverlight-asynchronous-code-with-specflow/

this may change as this was done with a pre release build, hopefully I'll get time to update it if it does.